# How to sort by within a Django list

Tags: python, django, generics, listview, sorting

This is a list of jobs and their prices.
I need help on the sorting. I want to make it so that when you click on sort by Budget, the list is ordered by budget decreasing, and when clicked again change to sort by budget increasing. I don't know if this requires a new page site/findjob/sortbybudget, but I prefer to do this within site/findjob. I would appreciate any help or references I can read up to do this.

**This is urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

from project.preview.models import Task

info_task = {
    'queryset': Task.objects.all(),
    'template_name': 'template.html',
}

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^findtask/$', 'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list', dict(info_task)),
)
```

**This is: template.html**

```
<div class="sortList">
**Sort by:**
<ul>
    <li class="sort"><a href=""/>Budget</a></li>
    <li class="sort"><a href=""/>Newly Added</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="taskListCon">
        {% for object in object_list %}
        <div class="taskCon">
          <div class="Title">
          {{ object.title_description }}
          </div>
          <div class="clientID">                    
          {{object.userid}}
          </div>
          <div class="Price">
          Budget:{{ object.max_budget }}
        </div>
<div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, the solution i propose is to enjoy a reusable app that does it right.

> [django-tables2](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2)
>   simplifies the task of turning sets of data into HTML tables. It has
>   native support for pagination and sorting. It does for HTML tables
>   what django.forms does for HTML forms. e.g.
>
> Its features include:
>
> - Any iterable can be a data-source, but special support for Django querysets is included.
> - The builtin UI does not rely on JavaScript.
> - Support for automatic table generation based on a Django model.
> - Supports custom column functionality via subclassing.
> - Pagination.
> - **Column based table sorting.**
> - Template tag to enable trivial rendering to HTML.
> - Generic view mixin for use in Django 1.3.

[Screenshot](https://camo.githubapp.com/ae16ad2805b12501096cba8411b2786a9885421b/687474703a2f2f646c2e64726f70626f782e636f6d2f752f33333439393133392f646a616e676f2d7461626c6573322f6578616d706c652e706e67)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use something like jQuery tablesorter to solve this. This will save you a roundtrip to the server for each sort.

Docs: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the use of django-filter. Just check out the example app:

https://github.com/alex/django-filter

Comment: If you go down this route, tastypie is a better option IMO.